React/Typescript (Vite) : Cannot find name 'type_name'. ts(2304)
I've created a React app with TypeScript using the following vite command:
npm create vite@latest

The auto-import for typescript's type is not working. Previously, it was working without any tweek in the config files.
say I've got a Type Name in types/index.ts file
type Name = {
 firstName : string,
 lastName: string
}

But the auto-import is not working with the react components - Test.
type Collection= {
 students : Name[]
}

export default function Test() {
   return (
      <div>test</div>
    )
 }

tsconfig.json
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}

tsconfig.app.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

tsconfig.node.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.node.tsbuildinfo",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}


Sorry but what is "auto-import"? It's not a Vite feature that I can find any sort of reference to

@Phil I meant default import, make Name type available in react components without its import statement.

Again, no idea what that is. Can you provide a link to some sort of reference describing this "feature". The closest I can find is this unplugin-auto-import utility

@Phil I don't know what the name of this feature is. In my 1-year-old React project, I was able to use types defined in the types/index.ts file in React components without an import statement (that's what I've shown above). Now it is not possible, without explicit export and import statements.

Guess you are talking about "when there is no import/export, all files can use anything in the other files" (there should be a term but I forgot)

@Jerryh001 is it something standalone?

Ambient (finally found the name), this feature is commonly used in old JS code (because there is no bundler) or define something globally in d.ts, and not suggest to use it in normal(modern) .ts files because it block some optimize of the transpiler
